# I cannot get value in selectOneMenu using JSF. return null in variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have problem to get value in selectOneMenu, I tried search in web  other examples and it's similar but not working.

Let me explain...below you can find my XHTML page:

```
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/template/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">

    <script>
        function setUploadFilesCount() {
            var i = 0;
            var numberOfFiles = $('.ui-fileupload-preview').size();
            var input = document.getElementById('fileupload-multi-fix-input');
            input.value = numberOfFiles;
            input.onchange();           
        }   
  </script>

    <ui:include src="/sections/crud/scc/sccReport.xhtml"/>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />  

    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

        <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="null">
            <p:tab title="Allowed Report Types:">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="20">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="blablablablablablabla" />

                    <h:outputText
                        value="blablablablablablabla" />    

                    <h:outputText
                        value="blablablablablablabla" />    
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>

        <br />
        <br />

        <h4>1) Select the Report:</h4>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="reportOption" value="#{sccReportController.reportOption}" required="true" label="Report Option">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Report 1" itemValue="report1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Report 2" itemValue="report2" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Report 3" itemValue="report3" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
        <br />
        <br />

        <h4>2) Select and upload all log files that will be processed:</h4>

        <p:fileUpload 
            fileUploadListener="#{sccReportController.handleFileUpload}" 
            mode="advanced" 
            dragDropSupport="false"
            multiple="true" 
            update="messages" 
            fileLimit="1000" 
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|txt)$/"
            onstart="setUploadFilesCount()" />

    </h:form>

    <h:form prependId="false" style="display:none;">
        <h:inputText id="fileupload-multi-fix-input" value="#{sccReportController.numberOfUploadFiles}">
        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form"  />
        </h:inputText>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

and follow my Java Class

```
/**
  * The Class SccReportController.
*/

@Controller
@ManagedBean
@Scope("view")
public class SccReportController {

final static private String DIRECTORY = "c:\\temp\\";
final static private String DIRECTORY_TEMPORARY = "c:\\temp\\temporary_folder";

private String reportOption;

private int uploadCount = 0;
private int numberOfUploadFiles;

private StreamedContent file;
private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File> ();


public String getReportOption() {
    return reportOption;
}

public void setReportOption(String reportOption) {
    this.reportOption = reportOption;
}

public int getNumberOfUploadFiles() {
    return numberOfUploadFiles;
}

public void setNumberOfUploadFiles(int numberOfUploadFiles) {
    this.numberOfUploadFiles = numberOfUploadFiles;
}

public StreamedContent getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(DIRECTORY_TEMPORARY, event.getFile().getFileName()));

    try {
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            }

    uploadCount++;

    if(uploadCount == numberOfUploadFiles){

         File fFolder = new File(DIRECTORY_TEMPORARY);

         for(File file: fFolder.listFiles()){
             files.add(file);
         }

    }
}
```

}

when I debug this code I don't receive any value in String reportOption.
The reportOption return null.

Could you please help me understand the problem in my code??

Thanks.

att;

André

Comment: Have you tried submitting the form? When do you expect `reportOption` to have a value?

Comment: On behalf of @Seraphstryfe : Have you tried submitting the form? When do you expect `reportOption` to have a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add "process=@this" in ajax event
like this

```
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this"
                            update="@this"></p:ajax>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering a question. Could you edit your question to explain better *why* this would fix the OP's problem or maybe link to (and quote from) some kind of documentation? That way in the future, when people arrive at this question with the same problem, they might be able to understand better and infer a solution to their problem even if it doesn't exactly match this one.

Comment: Hey. I actually solved this problem a long time ago and so i cant remember doc or link. But the reason is this problem probably wrong used layout or form.

Comment: Hi Aylan, your code working now. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According with awnser from Ayhan Arslan I put the code below inside the selectOneMenu

```
 <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@this"></p:ajax>
```

So, it's working now and I change the selectOneMenu code to:

```
h4>1) Select the Report:</h4>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="reportOption" value="#{sccReportController.reportOption}" required="true" label="Report Option">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="MGW SCC Report" itemValue="MGWSCC" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="MSC SCC Report" itemValue="MSCSCC" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="MSC SCC + VLR Active User + HLR Provisioned Subscribers Report" itemValue="MSCVLR" />

                    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@this"> // I added this code line according with Ayhan Arslan anwser</p:ajax>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

        <br />
        <br />
```